# Selenium tests on Dell precision 5550: Certain thermal settings trigger "chrome not reachable" error

Tags: google-chrome, cpu, power-management, dell-precision, selenium

For our web based applications, we have created automated end to end tests. Those run in parallel, so we have a usage of nearly constantly 100 % on all CPU cores over more than 14 minutes.

On complete test run consists of 800 tests. The tests run against the current version of chrome. The node packages involved are also up to date.

The number of parallel running browser instances is at most 12.

When selecting "Thermal setting" = "Optimzied" in Dell Power Manager, I see between 0 and 4 error messages "chrome not reachable" in one complete test run.

When selecting "Thermal setting" = "Quiet" in Dell Power Manager, the tests runs without showing the "chrome not reachable" error. The CPU runs at a lower clock rate than in "Optimized" mode.

I have seen these behaviour since about one year already.

Do you have an idea, how to find the root cause of this behaviour?

Comment: Does your CPU speed get throttled in "Optimized" mode? You can usually see this in Task manager > Performance > CPU. If the thermal setting is the only change you make, then it is probably just because "Quiet" mode runs your cpu at a more stable speed for selenium. The root cause is likely to be some kind of timing bug with Selenium/WebDrivers/ChromeDriver (so make sure those are up to date)